# Нужно ли объявлять переменные в php?

Tags: php, переменные

Привет всем. Как **правильней** проверить существование и установить глобальные переменные:

```
1. $_SESSION['user'] = $_SESSION['user'] ? : "";
2. $_SESSION['user'] = isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "";
```

Первый вариант короче и на локалке не вызывает никаких warnings и errors у интерпретатора. Будет ли от так же работать и на реальных серверах? Не вызовет ли исключение, что "переменная $_SESSION не определена"?

Comment: isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : ""; вот так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный 2 вариант. На первом варианте должно выводить сообщение "warning" ( Разумеется зависимо от настроек сервера)